# How can I avoid wasteful copying of keys in a B-tree based STL-like map?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, undefined-behavior, b-tree

I'm replacing a use of `std::map` in a hot path with [cpp-btree](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/)'s `btree_map`.  But with optimization enabled, GCC and Clang complain about a strict aliasing violation.  The problem boils down to this:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class btree_map {
public:
    // In order to match the standard library's container interfaces
    using value_type = std::pair<const Key, Value>;

private:
    using mutable_value_type = std::pair<Key, Value>;

    struct node_type {
        mutable_value_type values[N];
        // ...
    };

public:
    class iterator {
        // ...

        value_type& operator*() {
            // Here we cast from const std::pair<Key, Value>&
            // to const std::pair<const Key, Value>&
            return reinterpret_cast<value_type&>(node->values[i]);
        }
    };

    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& value) {
        // ...
        // At this point, we have to insert into the middle of a node.
        // Here we rely on nodes containing mutable_value_type, because
        // value_type isn't assignable due to the const Key member
        std::move_backward(node->values + i, node->values + j,
                           node->values + j + 1);
        node->values[i] = value;
        // ...
    }
};
```

This got me thinking, is there a way to do this as efficiently that doesn't rely on undefined behaviour?  The keys I'm using are efficiently moveable but fairly slow to copy, so I'd love to avoid copying many keys on every insertion.  I've considered

- Using `value_type values[N]`, then `const_cast<Key&>(values[i].first) = std::move(key)` to move the key around, but I'm pretty sure that's still undefined
- Returning `std::pair<const Key&, Value&>` instead of `std::pair<const Key, Value>&` when appropriate, but I'm not sure this would still satisfy the container requirements (I hear `...::reference` is supposed to really be a reference type)
- Not caring.  The code works as-is, but I'm curious if it can be done in a standard-compliant way.  There's also the chance that future compilers do different things with the UB, and I don't know of a way to apply `-fno-strict-aliasing` to only a single class.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Gcc provides [may_alias attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313050/gcc-how-to-use-attribute-may-alias-properly-to-avoid-derefencing-type), this works like -fno-strict-aliasing but only in expressions involving the particular variable(s) with may_alias attribute.

Comment: True.  (You mean `may_alias` right?)  I wonder if there's a way to do it without langauge extensions though.

Comment: do you must use ad-hoc C-array? and do you must use array of objects or you can use array  of pointers?

Comment: @user3613500 Storing an array of pointers in addition to the pairs themselves would probably use too much space.  It doesn't have to be a "C array", I'm open to things like `std::aligned_storage<...>::type` and placement new as long as the performance and memory layout stays the same.

Comment: well , you going to sacrifice something , if not memory then runtime, if not runtime then simplicity of the code. I think using array of pointers instead of regular array of objects solves your problem of copying if each std::pair is bigger than sizeof(std::pair*)

Comment: just fyi, in [boost::flat_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html) they define `value_type` simply as `typedef std::pair< Key, T >`

Comment: @user3613500 In this instance, I would much rather sacrifice code simplicity than memory or performance.

Comment: @frymode Good point.  I'd love to keep the extra safety of `const Key` in the interface but maybe it's not practical.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule),

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - ...
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), ...

Hence going from std::pair<Key,Value> to std::pair<const Key, Value> via intermediate cast to a union or a struct containing both types as members won't break strict aliasing rules.

Caveat: std::pair in a union is not permited until C++11, can use a structure instead.

Caveat: assumption that the two pair types have compatible layouts may not hold true. Imagine an implementation that orders first and second differently depending on the constness of the Key type.

Comment: I could define my own `pair<>` type to be sure of the layout.  But even still, a cast like `reinterpret_cast<A&>(reinterpret_cast<ABUnion&>(b))` doesn't really save you does it?  In the end you're still accessing an object of type `B` through an lvalue of type `A`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes do not apply another typecast to the union reference, use field access instead. This is unspecified behavior prior to c11/c++11, c11 guarantees it works right. Not sure if it is fine to use a structure instead of a union, probably not.

Comment: Okay good point.  If my reading of the standard is accurate then that's well defined as long as `pair<Key, Value>` and `pair<const Key, Value>` have a *common initial subsequence* containing `first` and `second`, which is only possible if `Key` and `Value` themselves are standard-layout types.  So it would work for `btree_map<int, int>` but not necessarily `btree_map<std::string, std::string>` for example.

Answer (score 4):

*Modified: expanded `move_backward(...)` into for-loop with explicit destructor call and placement new to avoid assignment error.*

Placement new can be used instead of simple assignment.

*Note: this implementation below is not exception-safe. Additional code is required for exception-safety.*

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class btree_map {
// ...
private:
    struct node_type {
        // Declare as value_type, not mutable_value_type.
        value_type values[N];
        // ...
    };

    class iterator {
        // ...

        value_type& operator*() {
            // Simply return values[i].
            return node->values[i];
        }
    };

    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& value) {
        // ...
        // expand move_backward(...)
        for(size_t k = j + 1; k > i; k--) {
            // Manually delete the previous value prior to assignment.
            node->values[k].~value_type();
            // Assign the new value by placement new.
            // Note: it goes wrong if an exception occurred at this point.
            new(&node->values[k]) value_type(node->values[k - 1]);
        }
        // Matual delete and placement new too.
        node->values[i].~value_type();
        // Note: it goes wrong if an exception occurred at this point.
        new (&node->values[i]) value_type(value);
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: But `std::move_backward` won't compile because `value_type` isn't assignable

Comment: Sorry, `std::move_backward` should be replaced with placement new loop. I fixed the code.

Comment: That loop will be doing copy construction though, not move construction.  And even if you add `std::move(node->values[k - 1])` it will still do copy construction of the key because `value_type`'s move constructor can't move from the `const` field `first`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not use BTREE as a replacement balanced binary tree with no reason: usually it is because you have a physical storage which is much slower and works as block-device that you need to use an array in a node which "somewhat" represents the device block. So trying to optimize the cycles spent in handling internal array is pretty marginal.

However, I suspect N is the key factor in :

```
struct node_type {
    mutable_value_type values[N];
    // ...
};
```

If it is small enough, you may not need to insert/lookup/remove an element in key order. The performance could be better than trying to order them in a small array. To avoid any move in Remove function, you could also define an empty slot so that Remove will just replace an element with an empty slot and Insert will replace the first met empty slot with an element.

For bigger array, you could use two arrays : one will contain as element a pair consisting of a key and an index/iterator pointing to the value stored in the second array. That way, you can still sort the first array fast regardless the type of `value_type`. That said, you still need to handle the second array when inserting or removing an element. The first array may also contain special pairs with pre-allocated indices in the second array when creating a node. A special pair is also set at removal of an element (keeping the index for later insertion of another element). When sorting the first array those special pairs will be put at the end. And knowing the count of inserted elements, you could use it as an index to allocate the first special pair to insert an element (allocating in second array) at O(1). At removal of an element, a special pair can replace the normal pair (keeping the index) in the first array just before sorting it. And you just need to use a placement new call or a destructor call on the current element (insertion or removal).

Comment: I suspect the "slow" external storage in this case in main memory. BTrees can be faster than binary trees in modern systems because of higher cache efficiency and less pointer chasing.

Comment: true if the size of a pair is small enough to allow several elements in the cache. Even so, sorting the internal array is probably not necessary. I mean, using a `std::vector< std::pair< key, value > >` instead of `std::map< key, value >` may be faster because the count of element is low.